# how can I always show step values along with a custom text describing the step values in angular material?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, angular-material

How can I always show step values along with a custom text describing the step values in angular material ?
I want the number on the top and the text at the bottom.

[image]

Comment: what exactly you want to do and what you tried? first share your one.

Comment: selectionChange is your friend

Answer (score 0):

The `mat-horizontal-stepper` has the property to position the text/ label in the bottom. You can use the label to describe the stepper value. The stepper value appears on top and label in bottom.

All you need is adding `labelPosition="bottom":

```
<mat-horizontal-stepper labelPosition="bottom" #stepper>
  <mat-step>
    ...
    <div>
      <button mat-button matStepperPrevious>Back</button>
      <button mat-button matStepperNext>Next</button>
    </div>
  </mat-step>
</mat-horizontal-stepper>
```

More here: https://material.angular.io/components/stepper/overview

Here is an example by Angular Material:

[Label position - Angular Material Stepper](https://stackblitz.com/angular/moynjyeabome?file=app%2Fstepper-label-position-bottom-example.ts)